# Getting width() of <li> only the parent <li>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out the parent <*li>'s width only, I have menu which has sub menus, I dont want the script to find all the sub-menus's <*li>, just the parent <*li> width is required, below is my function that returns the width, however the width is supposed to be 760 but I get 811, I believe its also adding all the li within a class..

```
 menuwidth = 0;
 jQuery(".menuclass li").each(function() {
     menuwidth += jQuery(this).width();      
 });
```

I tried giving outerwidth() with true as well, innerWidth(), but nothing returns the expected value.. what am I doing wrong here..

regards

Comment: post the little bit of HTML and I could be more help

Comment: An li is always as wide as its widest child

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about the selector. If you just want the li's just inside the .menuclass... then you can do `.menuclass > li` and it'll just grab the top tier and not the `.menuclass li li li li` etc

Comment: in the demo, it returns perfect, not sure what is wrong, http://jsfiddle.net/jD9P3/ let me dig more.. thanks for your reply though..